# BLE read write and notify error , 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x80650081

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, read-write, bluetooth-gatt

I am writing an application to read from and write to a bluetooth low energy device(indoor bicycle trainer) and i am trying to write the values to its characteristics.

I am following the microsoft.com BLE code program.

but each time i want to write the values it give me an unexpected error which is 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x80650081'     which is even not on the internet and i don't know whats kind of problem is occuring.

even though my code is ok and it is reading the value from the device. I have read somewhere that it might be the problem with bios of your device or the operating system. I have tried to run it on other PC it is still showing the same error.

As per the documentation of the fitness machine trainer i am sending the right OP code and Bytes but still it is not working.

can i get some feedback and review of my code so i can know where i am making mistake.

```
else if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Write))
{
              // This characteristic supports writing to it.
Console.WriteLine($"\t\t[{characteristic.Uuid}] write property found");
var writer = new DataWriter();
             // WriteByte used for simplicity. Other common functions - WriteInt16 and WriteSingle
writer.WriteByte(0x00);

GattCommunicationStatus resultWrite = await characteristic.WriteValueAsync(writer.DetachBuffer());

// the error shows here which leads to break the execution.
                                            
if (resultWrite == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)

{

Console.WriteLine("Control Request access");
}

writer = new DataWriter();
writer.WriteByte(0x01);
resultWrite = await characteristic.WriteValueAsync(writer.DetachBuffer());

if (resultWrite == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
{
Console.WriteLine("Reset request access");
// Successfully wrote to device
}
writer = new DataWriter();
 writer.WriteByte(0x04);
writer.WriteByte(0x64);
                                        

resultWrite = await characteristic.WriteValueAsync(writer.DetachBuffer());
if (resultWrite == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
{
Console.WriteLine("Resistance request access");
// Successfully wrote to device
}
}
```

i have tried different methods for writing e.g writesingle, writeInt16 etc and i got the same error.

also i want to know if the WriteValueAsync(writer.DetachBuffer()); has the problem or are there alternative ways to do it.

Comment: The 0x80650081 is E_BLUETOOTH_ATT_PROTOCOL_ERROR. The error usually appears if you are trying to send incorrect data or if trying to use incorrect write procedure (Write without response instead of Write or Write instead of Write Without Response)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.
I have wirtten the data Bytes over the device using raspberryPi, it was working.
but if i try it using this code then it throws error, 
also the gatt property is not write without response characteristic, it is only write property.
can it still be written using write without response? beacuse it will not detect it at the if condition.

Comment: GattCommunicationStatus resultWrite = await characteristic.WriteValueAsync(writer.DetachBuffer(), (GattWriteOption)BluetoothCacheMode.Cached);-
_
_
_
_
_ i added some change in the code which is (GattWriteOption)BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached/Cached; ------ then it is not showing error but it is still not writing the values.

Comment: I have read somewhere that it sometimes occurs becuase the data is not being stored or it may have problem with OS, i have tried it on other computers but it showing the same error.
I am following the microsoft.com uwp application it is working for others devices using the same procedure. but for my device i may be using the wrong procedure or making mistake somewhere.

Comment: It is very hard to say what can be wrong without known more details about your device.

Comment: My device is DiretoXR indoor trainer, and it have a documentation on the bluetooth.com for the fitness machine.
with the UUID of "1826" write property =>
2AD9 for fitness machine control point, 2AD6 Supported Resistance level Range and so on.

Comment: It is not possible to say what device requires without known its documentation. It may require authentication, writing to other char before allows to write to required one. Anything.

Comment: What kind is the app you are developing? UWP or a normal desktop app like WPF?

Comment: I am devloping UWP application, the same application is working for other devices and it is wirting or reading data from the devices. 

I think the i am making mistake somewhere in application procedure.
I tried to write the data on this device using raspberryPi it was fine so the device is accepting value and  the property was simple write Flag..